# How to resolve the validateDOMNesting(...): <form> cannot appear as a descendant of <form> error React JS

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-hook-form

I have a parent component and child component, When I call my child component inside the parent component onSubmit is not triggered.

I will share the CodeSandbox link below:

https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-morning-s4kni?file=/src/App.js

I get this error:
[image: Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): cannot appear as a descendant of .]

Answer (score 0):

`form` cannot contain another `form` element per spec: https://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#prohibitions

What you can do it is just place them as neighbours in the tree, it will look identical, but will work fine without bugs:

```
      <div>
        <form id="parentform" onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
          <input
            {...register('firstName', { required: true, maxLength: 20 })}
          />
          <input {...register('lastName', { pattern: /^[A-Za-z]+$/i })} />
          <input type="number" {...register('age', { min: 18, max: 99 })} />
          <input id="btnparent" type="submit" />
        </form>
        <div id="childdiv">
          <Child />
        </div>
      </div>
```

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/https-stackoverflow-com-questions-70984361-co3hk?file=/src/App.js)